# Islam.SE temporary logo — can we vote?

Tags: discussion, design

Let's vote on a different temporary logo (also known as "favicon" or "icon").  Please keep discussion at this post: [Change the Islam.SE favicon (currently "Is") to something Islamic?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/change-the-islam-se-favicon-currently-is-to-something-islamic-any-more-can)  ***This post is for voting.***

I ask:

- ***Please only upvote one candidate***; we have no real way to verify this (I trust you),
- ***Downvotes indicate strong disagreement***, e.g., "*hold on, you've missed something important*".

---

*Chinese.SE* experience:  I plan to organize this as at [Chinese.SE](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1603/chinese-language-temporary-logo-can-we-vote).  We mostly reached a consensus there, and nobody raised major objections, so the winner 漢 is [now proposed](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1634/lets-change-the-temporary-logo-from-cn-to-%EF%A9%87) (and hopefully it's in the works).

So...

- I select the candidates that I think have a chance of winning.
- I present them completely without context (as they would appear in the "Hot Network Questions" etc.).
- The currently logo is "Is" or "IS" depending on where you look.  Noone thus far has indicated a preference for "Is" over any of the candidates.  Other examples: Chess.SE uses a rook ♜, Poker.SE uses a club ♣.

(If we don't reach a consensus, hopefully we can at least eliminate most candidates, then maybe have a second round of voting with two remaining candidates.)

---

What we need to consider:

1. The logo is mostly going to look very small, and needs to fit into a square.  It'll likely look slightly different than the characters below.
2. It'll almost certainly be plain white text on a blue background (like all the others).
3. The logo would be able to be seen by everyone (so there's potential for mistreatment).
4. Islam.SE does not favor a particular denomination.
5. I'd argue it's sensible to *minimize controversy*.
6. If you can't vote for religious reasons (e.g., I could imagine someone not wanting to downvote certain icons), then perhaps leave a comment.  But we are just voting on the use of an icon for an Internet site.

Comment: Maybe we can call this off now?  We're not reading a conclusion.  I think the next step is [Would you be happy with this hand-drawn Kufic-style “Islam” اسلام as a favicon?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3451/would-you-be-happy-with-this-hand-drawn-kufic-islam-%d8%a7%d8%b3%d9%84%d8%a7%d9%85-as-a-favicon)

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our Community Managers from last week: [Custom Islam Stack Exchange design and logo - Information gathering](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3576/46770) :)

Comment: Update: [Your new site design is live!](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3649/46770)

Answer (score 5):

## ﷲ

## الله

Comment: I'll put these together; if necessary, we can later discuss typography.

Comment: If this is win, I propose kufic script

Comment: @Rafid I agree Kufic would be the best bet, but until they get around to giving us a proper new full site design we're mostly limited to the same standard fonts every other site uses. Not a lot to work with there.

Comment: I voted this because this is what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam) also used, and also because it's compact enough. I think commonality will make it easier to identify, even for non-Muslim users.

Answer (score 5):

## اسلام

Comment: I seriously doubt this would look any good in the tiny space provided. The vast majority of logos only have two characters in them, I don't think I've ever seen one that has more than three.

Comment: @goldPseudo we can use kufic script, Engineer knows best

Comment: @Rafid I agree Kufic would be the best bet, but until they get around to giving us a proper new full site design we're mostly limited to the same standard fonts every other site uses. Not a lot to work with there.

Comment: @goldPseudo so we cant use image as favicon?

Comment: Please keep discussions here: [Change the Islam.SE favicon (currently “Is”) to something Islamic?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/change-the-islam-se-favicon-currently-is-to-something-islamic)

Answer (score 4):

## ☪︎

Answer (score 3):

## ۩

Answer (score 1):

## ۞

Answer (score -1):

## Is

(no change)

Comment: Just in case...