# Would you be happy with this hand-drawn Kufic-style "Islam" اسلام as a favicon?

Tags: discussion, design

- I think we're all happy about changing the icon [Change the Islam.SE favicon (currently "Is") to something Islamic?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/change-the-islam-se-favicon-currently-is-to-something-islamic)
- But I don't think we're going to reach a consensus anytime soon unless things change: [Islam.SE temporary logo — can we vote?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3440/islam-se-temporary-logo-can-we-vote)

My impression is that we *might* be able to get everyone on board with "Islam" in Arabic, i.e., اسلام, as an icon... *provided we can reasonably squeeze it in the smallest icon*.

[Rafid suggested](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3440/islam-se-temporary-logo-can-we-vote/#comment7990_3445) using Islam اسلام in Kufic script.  So I attempted it myself: [image] (main) [image] (meta).

**Question**: Would you be happy with this hand-drawn Kufic-style "Islam" اسلام as a favicon?

I couldn't find something online, so I drew it myself.  This is my first attempt at a Kufic drawing, so please let me know if it needs fixing (it's probably not perfect).  Or, better yet, please open up e.g. paintbrush and do so, and post an improvement as an answer.

In any case---it's only a temporary icon.

The 16x16 icon is hardest to draw.  I expect it'd be comparatively straightforward to do the other-sized icons.  I might do so if there's a chance we can make it work.

Actually, it was very little effort to make corresponding 32x32 icons; just make the lines twice as thick:

[image] [image]

The current icon is [image], and some alternatives (drawn by me) are [image] and [image] (abbreviation "اس" just for this smallest icon).

---

There seems to be some flexibility:

- Bricks's logo: [image] (a simple image)
- CiviCRM's logo: [image] (a simple image)
- CraftCMS's logo: [image] (red)
- HSM's logo: [image] (rectangular)
- Chinese's logo: [image]  We got it [changed a few days ago](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1634/lets-change-the-temporary-logo-from-cn-to-%EF%A9%87) because we [managed to agree](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1603/chinese-language-temporary-logo-can-we-vote).

Comment: I'm sorry to act as a blocker but unless this is part of a unicode character set, we can't use custom art, even if y'all create it. I need to be extremely limiting in what I ask our branding team to do so the guidelines are pretty strict. Until this site gets approved for a full site design or we change the process somehow, you'll need to stick to basic (non-emoji) text.

Comment: @Catija: Thanks for letting us know.  The problem is that اسلام (Islam, in Arabic) and الله (Allah = God, in Arabic) is what [we're voting on](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3440/islam-se-temporary-logo-can-we-vote), but they're both long.  Would you be able to comment on whether اسلام would fit please?  I made a mock-up of this too [above] (which doesn't seem too horrible).  Using Allah as an icon might be regarded as a bit iffy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't really matter... this idea is out.  (It was an enjoyable exercise, though.)

> I'm sorry to act as a blocker but unless this is part of a unicode character set, we can't use custom art, even if y'all create it. I need to be extremely limiting in what I ask our branding team to do so the guidelines are pretty strict. Until this site gets approved for a full site design or we change the process somehow, you'll need to stick to basic (non-emoji) text. – [Catija♦ Jan 30 at 20:34](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3451/would-you-be-happy-with-this-hand-drawn-kufic-style-islam-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85-as-a-favicon#comment8003_3451)

Answer (score 2):

I am fine with straight lines instead of curves, although I dislike calligraphy which messes with letter orientations and joints. Seeing this icon without any context it would be hard to guess that اسلام is written. Maybe someone will even think that the site is about mazes.

Comment: That's a fair point.  Although I suppose anything writing in Arabic will make people think it's a site about learning Arabic.

Answer (score 1):

I think all of them look fine.

However I personally would prefer something more simple like the Andalus font:
[image]

Or the Arabswell font which looks close to the original scripture of the early Mushafs and is still in use
[image]

Or even a simple kufic scripture as long as it can be easily deciphered.

So for a better recognition I'd vote for something like:
[image]

as not many people like to solve or are familiar with complex calligraphy's.