# Islam.SE temporary logo... What are your current thoughts?

Tags: discussion, design

From [Islam.SE temporary logo — can we vote?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3440/islam-se-temporary-logo-can-we-vote), the current scores are:

- (+5/-1) اسلام (Islam)
- (+4/-1) ﷲ الله (Allah)
- (+2/-0) ۩
- (+2/-0) ☪︎
- (+1/-0) ۞
- (+1/-1) Is (leave it alone).

Thanks for everyone who voted.  It seems we need to continue discussing this.

**Question**: What are your current thoughts?

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our Community Managers from last week: [Custom Islam Stack Exchange design and logo - Information gathering](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3576/46770) :)

Comment: (Sorry for the multiple notifications; I'm just trying to leave signposts from relevant posts to the recent one.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my thoughts (please share yours):

#### اسلام

- *Pro*: It's popular, and it's the obvious uncontroversial choice.  If we could make this work, it'd be great.
- *Con*: It's wide.  I tried to find [a workaround](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3451/would-you-be-happy-with-this-hand-drawn-kufic-style-islam-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85-as-a-favicon), but that didn't work.  It's probably going to look crammed [image], unless the smallest icon is abbreviated [image].

Maybe we need to declare this as *impractical* and move on to something else.

#### الله

- *Pro*: I expect this would be straightforward to implement.  It's also popular.
- *Con*: I feel "iffy" using Allah in a for-profit company icon.  However, I'm not strongly against it.

#### ۩

- *Pro*: It's simple, and you can see this design at mosques and halal restaurants.  It also seems uncontroversial.
- *Con*: What is it going to look like?  It looks different on different devices.  Will the icon look like a mushroom?  [Maybe I'll try some mock-ups of this.]

#### ☪︎

- *Pro*: A lot of people already think this is an Islamic icon.
- *Con*: There is a reasonable argument that this is Sunni-centric.  I think this is a reasonable objection, enough to make me think we should avoid it.

#### ۞

I don't like this one.  It doesn't scream "Islam" to me.  And it's similar to Buddhism.SE [image].

#### Is

- *Pro*: It's fairly uncontroversial, and we're used to it.
- *Con*: It's not very Islamic.

I guess doing nothing is indeed a possibility.  It's probably not such a big deal, and it would prevent anyone being upset that their choice wasn't used.

Answer (score 0):

How about a graphic that is easily recognizable as a mosque?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Basically this is the blockage: [we can't use custom art](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3451/would-you-be-happy-with-this-hand-drawn-kufic-style-islam-%d8%a7%d8%b3%d9%84%d8%a7%d9%85-as-a-favicon?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment8003_3451).  A while back Stack Exchange had a Zoom meeting, and I asked them about site design for smaller sites.  They basically said they'll report back in the near future.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I was expecting something like that, but thought if I don't ask I will not know for certain ;) On the  other hand I'm not too familiar with unicode.